# error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: git, curl

I have tried answers in similar questions but didn't work. Even after setting https.postBuffer to 500MB  the problem does not resolve.

```
Total 425 (delta 81), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Everything up-to-date

Comment: Please provide links to answers that you have tried.

Comment: Sorry couldn't update,
but it seemed the network issue.
With better one it pushed
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This is because of long process running in the server side.

If there is no repsonse from server side since a longtime, this error arises due to idle connection.

Just restart the concerned `webapp(azure)` or `dyno(heroku)` or wait wait until the process has completed. Everythinh works fine thereafter.